# How to speed up for initialization of imdb

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, deep-learning

While using deep learning with MATLAB I am experiencing complete memory usage while making imdb for the first image. So I decided to initialize first image data with zeros like that:

```
image_size = [56 56];     
imdb.images.data   = zeros(image_size(1), image_size(2), 1, 30160, 'single');
imdb.images.labels = zeros(1, 30160, 'single');
imdb.images.set    = zeros(1, 30160, 'uint8');

for jj=1:61
    imdb.images.data(:,:,jj,1)=zeros(56,56);
end
```

I have 61 band images so 61 denotes that. My Pc is 16 GB RAM and 3.4GHZ i7 Processor.

Is there any way to speed up for this initialization?

Comment: `imdb.images.data` was already initialized when you created it with `zeros`.

Comment: imdb=image database. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 61 slices of 56x56 zeros, i.e. a 3D matrix, as given in the [documentation of `zeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) and store them in `imdb.images.data` in one go.

```
imdb.images.data = zeros(56,56,61);
```